# I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed. Can I install macOS (Hackintosh) alongside on any pc/laptop? (Dual boot)

Tags: dual-boot

I want to make dual boot with Ubuntu + macOS (Hackintosh). How Can I do this?

Please help me.

TIA :)

Regards,

Comment: Does the Mac OS run on the Dell?

Comment: We do not provide direct support for installing other OSes on the system alongside Ubuntu.  This includes Hackintosh or Windows.  This is offtopic.

Comment: Can usually install whatever OS or many OSs, you want onto your system.  Will they work or you make a mistake and over write your data is another question.

Comment: VirtualBox is a safe way to run other OS. It is also Third Party Software, which is allowed by the rules of AsK Ubuntu. Perhaps Google "running macos on Vbox". You will find lots of instructions.